# How can I print out <tr> after every 4 mysql entries in my while loop?

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

```
$q2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM artwork LEFT JOIN folder ON folder.folder_id=artwork.folder_id WHERE id IN(0".$userids.")");  
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q2)){

$link .= '<td align="center"><a href="/art/'.$row['id'].'" title="'.$row['name'].'">
            <img src="/img/artwork/'.$row['folder'].'/'.$row['file'].'" height="80" /></a><br />
            <span align="center"><a href="#">[remove]</a> <a href="/art/'.$row['id'].'">[view]</a></span></td>';
            }
```

link is getting echo'd out with one td, but I need to make it so after every 4 mysql entries it adds a tr

Comment: [`array_chunk`](http://au1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) would be a nice way to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just maintain a counter and test if it is divisible by 4:

```
$counter = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q2)) {
    if ($counter%4 === 0) $link .= "<tr>";
    $link .= "<td>...</td>";
    if ($counter%4 === 3) $link .= "</tr>";
    $counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable to count `td`'s and check if it's rminder by 4 is 0 then open an close `tr`

```
$item = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q2)) {
    if ($item  % 4 == 0) $link .= "<tr>";
    $link .= "<td>...</td>";
    if ($item % 4 == 0) $link .= "</tr>";
    $item++;
}
if($item  % 4 != 0){//IF COUNT OF TD IN LAST ROW IS LESS THAN 4
    while($item  % 4 != 0){
        $link.= "<td></td>";
        $item++;
    }
    $link.= "</tr>";
}
```